# Number of Non-Space Characters

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, if-statement

I have written a console application to count the number of non-space characters in a paragraph, but it is not working properly.

```
int l=0;
string s;

Console.WriteLine("Enter Paragraph: ");
s = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        l++;
    }
}

l = Convert.ToInt32(s.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Your Paragraph Length is: " + l);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: Your foreach loop only checks for letters.  Wouldn't that exclude more than just spaces (numbers, special chars)?

Comment: @SLacks it is working but i am unable to get results which i want. :( i want written characters only in my output let suppose i write ammar asjad
then it prints number of characters  as 11 but i want out put only characters and my characters are 10 . simply to say i want characters without spaces counting

Comment: You'll need to either store the characters you want to print, or convert the string somehow?  Not sure what results you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your question specifically strips out ONLY spaces...  It seems to me this would be more efficient:

```
        int l=0; 
        string s; 
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Paragraph: "); 
        s = Console.ReadLine(); 

        l = s.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Length; 
        Console.WriteLine("Your Paragraph Length is: " + l); 
        Console.ReadLine();
```

*If you want OTHER white space, like tabs and newlines, trimmed out as well, that would be a different story...*

Comment: thanks its working now :) if i want to trim characters?? then i will write l=s.replace("",String.Empty).Length;  ???

Comment: Replace([string], [string]) will replace whatever character you have in the first parameter with whatever you want in the second.  String.Empty evaluates to "".  You can alter it any way you like.

Comment: Thanks i find out exact solution:)

Answer (score 5):

For one you are over writing l with s.Length.  Two I dont't think : is a char.

```
l = Convert.ToInt32(s.Length);
```

Try

!Char.IsWhiteSpace will eliminate space, tab, ... which is probably what you are looking for.

[Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx)

```
    int l=0;
    string s;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Paragraph: ");
    s = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            l++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Your Paragraph Length is: " + l);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Borrowing from Skeet +1.  I need a little flasher when he is on line so I know know not to even try.

```
    count = line.Count(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

Comment: @AmmarAsjad: Blam did help out - what else do you want? Just remove this line and off you go.

Comment: thanks its working now :) if i want to trim characters?? then??

Comment: Define trim.   There are are String Trim methods.

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple with LINQ:

```
var nonSpaces = line.Count(c => c != ' ');
```

Or for letters:

```
var letters = line.Count(char.IsLetter);
```

This will execute a delegate for every character, but won't start creating extra strings you really don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
int c = "tada test me ".Replace(" ","").Length;
```

so in you case

```
#region number of characters other than spaces 
int l=0; 
string s; 
Console.WriteLine("Enter Paragraph: "); 
s = Console.ReadLine(); 
l = s.Replace(" ","").Length; 
Console.WriteLine("Your Paragraph Length is: " + l); 
Console.ReadLine(); 
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be

```
String noSpaces = s.Replace(" ", "");
return noSpaces.Length;
```